# ¿Cómo sacar un valor no repetido de un Array en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, números-enteros

tengo el siguiente Array

```
var arr = [4, 5, 5, 2, 2];
```

¿Cómo haría para sacar el valor que no está repetido? Es decir el número 4 (sin acceder a la posición)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una opción sería, realizar en primer lugar, ordenar el array de números haciendo uso del método [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort), para posteriormente filtrar [*filter*()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) los elementos donde la condición base sea, que la posición que retorne el método [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf) *(que retornará siempre el primer índice)* sea igual a al último indice haciendo uso de [lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/lastIndexOf)

```js
let arr = [4, 5, 5, 2, 2,5,3,8,9,9];
var arr2 = [4, 5, 5, 2, 2];
console.log(getNotRepeatInArray(arr));
console.log(getNotRepeatInArray(arr2));

function getNotRepeatInArray(arr){
  arr.sort();
  return arr.filter(function(a){
    return arr.indexOf(a) === arr.lastIndexOf(a)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer algo como esto

```js
var arr = [4, 5, 5, 2, 2];

function quitarDuplicados(arr){
    var arrayUnico = []
    for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arrayUnico.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1){
            arrayUnico.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return arrayUnico
}

console.log(quitarDuplicados(arr));
```

Comment: Edité su respuesta en un snippet, para ver el funcionamiento. pero al parecer no hace lo que pretende el OP, la finalidad es obtener los elementos que no se repiten **Solo esos valores.**

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia que es el OP?

Comment: Autor de la pregunta, el usuario que planteó la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución, en especial sin utilizar ninguna otra función de javascript, ni jquery, etc, también evitando reordenar el vector; digamos que sería una solución al estilo C pensando en algo "óptimo"

```js
var arr = [4, 5, 5, 2, 2, 9, 7];
 var i = 0;
 var encontrado = 0;
 for(;i<arr.length;i++)
 {
  encontrado = 0;
  for(j=i+1;(j<arr.length && encontrado == 0); j++)
  {
   if(arr[i]==arr[j])
   {
    delete arr[i];
    delete arr[j];
    encontrado++;
   }
  }
 }
 console.log(arr);
```

No sé sí esta mal en algo, probé con ese lote de pruebas y algunos mas.
Saludos.